# VSCode Intelliphense says "Use of unknown class: PHP(PHP0413)"

Tags: php

I've defined a class for connecting to MySQL databases through php.

It has worked fine for years but I've switched to VSCode for development and I'm wondering why VSCode/Intelliphense is failing to recognize the class.

Did I set up this class path improperly?

[image]

The code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require '../lib/Database.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$database = 'books';
$db = new Database($database);
$dbh = $db->getConnection();
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution was simple, I needed to leave off the closing `?>`, which was also suggested by Intelliphense.

Much ado about nothing.